# Android: Is there any way to detect any user input?

Tags: android

on Android! I need to get user input (touch event, keyboard event). is there any way? In java code, It seems there is no way. What about native code?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please try explaining further and sharing some code that you tried but not worked.

Comment: can you please tell what is the difference b/w Java Code and native code

Answer (score 1):

```
In java code, It seems there is no way.
```

=> sorry, there is a way to do detect any action user made and play with application.

Some examples:

1. [KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.html)
2. [Responding to Touch Events](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html)

Answer (score 0):

for touch you can use

```
mView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //show dialog here
    return false;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if your YourActivity implements OnTouchListener you can get the event and where the user touched on the screen:

```
   public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

     @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     System.out.println("I touched: "+event.getX()+"-"+event.getY());
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know what you exactly mean. Do you mean text input on an EditText or in General when something is touched?

If you mean text you can use TextWatcher
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

If you mean on a View directly you can use OnTouchListener as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction()

`Activity`

`public void onUserInteraction ()`

> Added in API level 3 Called whenever a key, touch, or trackball event
>   is dispatched to the activity. Implement this method if you wish to
>   know that the user has interacted with the device in some way while
>   your activity is running. This callback and onUserLeaveHint() are
>   intended to help activities manage status bar notifications
>   intelligently; specifically, for helping activities determine the
>   proper time to cancel a notfication.
>
> All calls to your activity's onUserLeaveHint() callback will be
>   accompanied by calls to onUserInteraction(). This ensures that your
>   activity will be told of relevant user activity such as pulling down
>   the notification pane and touching an item there.
>
> Note that this callback will be invoked for the touch down action that
>   begins a touch gesture, but may not be invoked for the touch-moved and
>   touch-up actions that follow.